# Analogue of associative arrays or hash tables in assembler

Tags: assembly, hashtable, masm

I am PHP programmer. For now I need to create simple script in masm where I need to use key => value pairs (ie fast selection value by key - one-to-one). The main idea is that keys can be strings. Is there any analogue of such feature (associative arrays, hash tables etc) in masm? What is the best way to do this correctly? Many thanks!

Comment: no. there's no hashes in assembler. There's arrays, but not hashes. hashes are a far "higher" concept. You'd have to implement your own hashing/bucket algorithms to create them.

Comment: @MarcB, many thanks! So which (in your opinion) the best way to implement such functionality? I understand that using dozens conditionals is ugly and dirty way - but which better here?

Comment: just how many items do you need to store in the hash table? If it's only a few dozen, just go quick 'n dirty and iterate over a standard array to check for string matches or whatever. If it's an arbitrary or "large" number, then you should dig up a real assoc array library for your assembler.

Comment: @MarcB, yes, standard way is most preferable here. But how to imitate key => value pair? Key - string, value - some number

Comment: I don't think there are any shortcuts, you'll have to implement a good hash function from string to int, use it to map into an array, and handle collisions (for e.g. have the array elements be lists of matching values along with full keys for matching)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Igor: Welcome to Assembler, where you have to build it yourself on top of the raw iron, or find a linkable library which has implemented this for you.

Most people that drop into assembler have something to do for which they expect there is no existing library (typically, high performance code for a funny task).

But if your assembler code if reasonably sized, you only want to write the high-performance part. Most of the rest of such programs is pretty vanilla stuff (open file, read record),... just you're stuck in assembler.

Here is where Linkage Editors are your friend.  Many higher level languages (C, C++, Fortran, Ada, COBOL :) actually compile to native assembler code.  This pretty much means that if you can find the routine you want, coded in such a language, you can find a way to call it from your assembler code.  The details of that depend on the compiler conventions for the high level language, and on the precise instruction set of the computer.  You can pretty much count on the core interface to use a CALL-subroutine machine instruction that the assembler does know about.   Finally, you have to explain to your assembler that you want it to link against the compiled code of interest, and learn how to use a link editor to stitch your code to the library you want.

For standard activities like File I/O, etc, invariably there is library made available that offers all the OS capabilities to the assembly language programmer.  (How otherwise would there be any higher level programming languages?)

So, what you should do is go fishing for C libraries that implement hash table, and then find out how to invoke them from your assembler.

Or, you can become a good assembly language programmer, and code these things yourself.
Depends on whether you want to spend a lot of time learning, or whether you just want to get the job done.

PS:  If you don't have something that has to be spectacularly fast, you're probably better off coding in C than coding in assembler.   You can still use those libraries :-}

PPS:  Considering you are a PHP programmer and use hashes every day because they are available, it may be that your thinking is contaminated by the way you use PHP.  Does your computation *really* need hashes, or will some other data structure work?

Comment: thanks for detailed answer! your guess is right - I need to do that task fast - it's a part of my institute's learning now:) So I need to do this part only with using assembler. I also tried to remember other known to me ways to implement it - and I think that linked list is easier to create than hash table etc.

Also, my task is sounds like "Create programm that will return machine code of given commands PUSH and POP" - (i/o by console) - ie on entered 'PUSH CS' program shall return '0E'. How do you think, which is the best way to create such feature without hash tables?Thanks!:)

Comment: Your first lesson is that you need to learn about data structures.  Hash tables are often built using linked lists.   If you understand data structures well, assembly language is just an ugly looking programming language.   If you don't understand data structures, you are not going to be able to write any interesting assembly code.  (I have no clue what you are being asked to do, based on your description).

Comment: oh, yes, when I learned that there are structures in assembler, I was pleased with it. So I can build linked lists as well.Excuse me for bad explanation - I'll try to explain again. So, the main idea is that after starting program (program is running in command line) user enter command PUSH with parameter and program returns him code of this command (example - enter 'PUSH CS', program returns 'OE'). All i/o (command that user enter and its code that program displays) via console. So I need to realize algorithm of forming and returning machine code of given command

Comment: I thought that associative array and linked list could help me with it. I will be very grateful for the help with it!:)

Comment: SO isn't about "give me the code".  So far you've said "I don't know how to do this".  Go read a technical book on data structures. Good ones will talk about building hash tables. You have no idea how good this advice is.  You won't get a lot of help until you demonstrate you've invested effort on your side.

Comment: sure -  I don't ask anybody for code. Just an idea that can be useful in my situation. I gave full description of my task just to make sure that I choosed right way to solve it. Left to read manuals about data structures:)

Comment: SO tries to keep it to "one question, corresponding answers".  Here you asked about writing hash tables in assembly code as your main question.  You've added another, "how do I convert 'PUSH CS' into '0E' (using an masm with a hash table)".  If this is a serious question on your part, start another SO question for it.  Hint: explain what you want to do at a high level more carefully.  My wild guess is you are trying to write a line-at-a-time assembler... using masm as the implementation langauge?  What would the point of that be? Don't answer here, put your discussion into another SO question.